# "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" in ipython notebook

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to ipython notebook, but I have the following error message whenever I run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I'm using Mac. It works fine with the built-in python or Canopy. The problem only exists with `ipython notebook`. I also tried to update the numpy, but the problem still exists. Would be grateful for someone to help!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6f467123fe04> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot

/Users/Michael/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 import matplotlib
---> 24 import matplotlib.colorbar
     25 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive
     26 from matplotlib.cbook import dedent, silent_list, is_string_like, is_numlike

/Users/Michael/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in <module>()
     27 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     28 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 29 import matplotlib.collections as collections
     30 import matplotlib.colors as colors
     31 import matplotlib.contour as contour

/Users/Michael/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in <module>()
     21 import matplotlib.artist as artist
     22 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 23 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
     24 import matplotlib.path as mpath
     25 from matplotlib import _path

/Users/Michael/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in <module>()
     48 
     49 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 50 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
     51 from matplotlib.path import Path
     52 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation

/Users/Michael/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py in <module>()
      9 from matplotlib.path import Path
     10 from matplotlib import rcParams
---> 11 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
     12 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
     13 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT

/Users/Michael/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in <module>()
     51 import matplotlib
     52 from matplotlib import afm
---> 53 from matplotlib import ft2font
     54 from matplotlib import rcParams, get_cachedir
     55 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Comment: Try running `ipython notebook --pylab`

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. I tried by got the error message below. I tried to install matplotlib again, and ran the program again, but still got the same error message in ipython notebook.

'WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
None                                      Traceback (most recent call last)
None: None
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Eventloop or matplotlib integration failed. Is matplotlib installed?'

Comment: it looks like your installation is borked.  Look like you are on a mac which seems to have endemic problems with getting the paths correct.  How did you install `matplotlib`/enthought?

Comment: I installed it through https://www.enthought.com/downloads/. I have just redownloaded and reinstalled the package but it still doesn't work. Indeed, I install ipython through Anaconda instead of Enthought Canopy because there is an error message "You are running enpkg as a root user inside a virtual environment. Please run it as a normal user" when I followed the installation instructions for Indeed, I install ipython through Anaconda instead of Enthought at http://ipython.org/install.html

Comment: As a Note, it appears the latest version of ipython notebook (as of today) does not support the --pylab option. In case anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 1):

How committed are you to Canopy? I had a few configuration issues attempting to use Canopy and ended up using Homebrew to customize my own Python install instead. There's a really helpful guide at:

http://joernhees.de/blog/2013/06/08/mac-os-x-10-8-scientific-python-with-homebrew/

I followed all of those steps except for two or three (don't remember which exactly) the "brew install" method didn't work and I had to pip the module instead.

I just opened up an IPython notebook to verify that everything works fine on my distribution.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The above gives me the expected output.